# UWP App crashes when downloaded from store, but not when sideloaded

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-native

My application (UWP,C#/xaml) works fine in release mode if I deploy it through Visual Studio, or if I sideload the appx on my phone.

But if I download it from store and run it, it crashes with the following exception

> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Also, the same app runs on PC without crashing on sideloading/loading through VS or even when downloaded from store.
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Code Snippet
>
private static Dictionary lockDictionary = new Dictionary();

```
    private static SemaphoreSlim getLockElement(string fileName)
    {
        if (lockDictionary.ContainsKey(fileName))
            return lockDictionary[fileName];
        else
        {
            SemaphoreSlim objectToReturn = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
            lockDictionary.Add(fileName, objectToReturn);
            return objectToReturn;
        }
    }

    private async static Task<StorageFile> getFile(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            return await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(key);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static async Task<string> readFileDataIndependentOfUserId(string key)
    {
        AccountFunctions.logMsg("Awaiting " + key);
        await getLockElement(key).WaitAsync();
        AccountFunctions.logMsg("Got into " + key);

        try
        {
            StorageFile File = await getFile(key);
            if (File == null)
                return null;
            string text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(File);

            return text;
        }
        finally
        {
            AccountFunctions.logMsg("Released " + key);
            getLockElement(key).Release();
        }
    }

    public static async Task saveDataInFileIndependentOfUserId(string key, string data)
    {
        AccountFunctions.logMsg("Awaiting " + key);
        await getLockElement(key).WaitAsync();
        AccountFunctions.logMsg("Got into " + key);

        try
        {
            var FileName = key;
            var Fileoption = CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting;
            var File = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName, Fileoption);
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(File, data);
            AccountFunctions.logMsg("Saving : " + key + " : " + data);
        }
        finally
        {
            AccountFunctions.logMsg("Released " + key);
            getLockElement(key).Release();
        }
    }

    public static async Task removeFileDataIndependentOfUserId(string key)
    {
        AccountFunctions.logMsg("Awaiting " + key);
        await getLockElement(key).WaitAsync();
        AccountFunctions.logMsg("Got into " + key);

        try
        {
            StorageFile File = await getFile(key);
            if (File == null)
            {
                getLockElement(key).Release();
                return;
            }
            await File.DeleteAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            AccountFunctions.logMsg("Released " + key);
            getLockElement(key).Release();
        }
    }
```

The crash occurs in constructor of my class containing these static functions. AccountFunctions.logMsg is a function that just writes to the debugger if attached.

Comment: Does it crash on the same machine that it also works correctly on?

Comment: Well, that should not happen.  Your app gets rebuilt on the Store server using .NET Native.  Which removes any dependency on a .NET assembly.  One issue with .NET Native is that reflection code is very troublesome, the build tool cannot see that you might have an indirect dependency.  Which is why you have .NET Native on your own machine so you can test such code.  Sounds like you skipped that test.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you please point me in the write direction? What test are you talking about? 

Also i am not really using reflection in my code.

Comment: @JohnieKarr It crashes on the same phone, on which it works if i sideload the app.

Comment: Agree with @HansPassant. Maybe you referenced something that is not developed by yourself? It is possible that the exception(first exception) got handled when you debugging the app, but not able to after the build on store like Hans mentioned. Check if you can find something like "Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll" in output window when debugging via visual studio. If so, the reflection is used somewhere in your project or referenced assembly.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblggh6h0sk is the link if any one can debug a store app in some way. The app crashes on clicking recharge after dismissing 2-3 popups. Also it is not throwing the exception in any one else's code. It is throwing it in my own function.

Comment: Added relevant code snippets where the crash is occuring.

@AlanYao-MSFT

Comment: It seems as though you may not have .NET Native enabled in your local builds. If you look at project properties > Build you'll see a checkbox for Enable .NET Native tool chain. Make sure that box is checked because that's the configuration you get built with in the Store. If you're still having issues, there's some info/tips here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/ilcRepro.md

Comment: @MattWhilden Adding <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
for each "Release" Property group in the .csproj files seems to have helped. 

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Please write the solution as an answer and i will mark it as answer :)

Comment: Hooray! Glad to hear you're back on track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as though you may not have .NET Native enabled in your local builds. If you look at project properties > Build you'll see a checkbox for Enable .NET Native tool chain. Make sure that box is checked for Release because that's the configuration you get built with in the Store.

The UWP template has this attribute added for RELEASE configurations: true. If you've migrated an old project to UWP it may be useful to diff your project file with the blank UWP template to see if there's any other oddities that may cause you trouble.